# Where data for auto-create caret tag in designMode/contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

I have created tag b and am typing characters in it.
I then remove characters with backspace.
The tag b disappears from the DOM tree.
Then I press any character and the tag b reappears.

Question: where is the information that a tag will appear when a key is pressed?

UPD: minimal reproducible example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre style='font-family: "Times";'>
    <div class="editor">Delete and create <b>Blod</b></div>
    <div class="editor">Delete and create <b>Blod</b><div>After element.</div></div>
</pre>
<script>
    document.designMode = "on";
    document.body.spellcheck = false;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to look at the DOM tree.
I also noticed an inadequate reaction if there is an element next.

[Sreenshots example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYSFy.png)

Comment: Although trivial in this OP, we do expect some code as a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I added code and screenshot

Comment: Can't reproduce behavior desribed with Win11 Chrome. What OS and browser are you experiencing said behavior?

Comment: Win7 Firefox 82

Comment: OK, in Win11 FF97 not only does it behave correctly, if you place the cursor in the `<b>` and backspace and then type something -- it's bold, which means that the `<b>` tag doesn't break like it does in Chrome. As for your problem, it is actually relevant despite the fact Win7 is no longer supported by M$, there is a ton of Win7 users still at large. Unfortunately, all of my older laptops are dead 